# Absolute File paths with Stylesheets CSS

Tags: php, html, css

Can anyone please tell me why the below will not and output the absolute filepath

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" <?php 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/styles/styles.css'; ?> " />
```

I'm trying to create a constant link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot to echo

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" <?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/styles/styles.css'; ?> " />
```

Comment: @dlhj happens to us all :)